# How can I deploy my maven project on Heroku?

Tags: java, mongodb, maven, heroku

My config.yml is defined as follow:

```
http:
    port: 8080
    adminPort: 8081

mongodb:
    default_database_uri: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/myappdb
```

I normally start `mongod` and run the app on localhost 8080 with

```
java -jar myapp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar server config.yml
```

I tried the following:

```
heroku deploy:jar myapp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar --app stark-sea-3911
```

But it didn't work.

My app is similar to this `https://github.com/mongodb-labs/socialite`

Answer (score 0):

Run this command:

```
heroku deploy:jar myapp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar --options "server config.yml" --app stark-sea-3911
```

If you don't want to add the `--options "server config.yml"` every time, you can either create a `Procfile` with the full command, or set `JAR_OPTS` on your app by running:

```
heroku config:set JAR_OPTS="server config.yml"
```

Also, make sure the `config.yml` is available on Heroku. You may need to also add `--includes config.yml` to your `deploy:jar` command.

You'll also probably want to change the http port stuff too look like this:

```
http:
    port: ${PORT}
```

Comment: what does PORT corresponds to?

Comment: The `PORT` env var will be set dynamically by Heroku. This is what your app needs to bind to in order to be exposed to the Heroku Router.